# Trouble setting UIButton title of selected Action picker item, SWIFT

Tags: swift, actionsheetpicker

I am finding trouble to set title for button of action picker item.

```
ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Select Nationality",  rows: [
        nationalityArray], initialSelection: [selectedNationalityIdStr],
                        doneBlock: {
                            picker, indexes, values in

                            let selectedEmirate = "\(values)"

                            self.btnNationality.setTitle(selectedEmirate, for: .normal)

                            print("values = \(values)")
                            print("indexes = \(finalIntId)")
                            print("picker = \(picker)")

                            return
    }, cancel:
        {
            ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return

    }, origin: sender)
```

the print of Values inside the Action sheet picker is this

```
values = Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600001ba1740>(Expat)
```

so when I write this below line to set title for a UIButton then it is setting up whole

```
 self.btnNationality.setTitle("\(selectedEmirate)", for: .normal)
```

As you can see here, it is taking whole values string instead of only "expat":
[image]

Some one help me setting up only "expat" from the values of my action sheet picker please

Comment: What is the type of your `nationalityArray` array is it [String] ?

Comment: @CodeChanger yes it is